# Enable/Disable textbox using Checkbox in wicket framework

Tags: java, wicket

i would like to do Enable/Disable textbox using Checkbox in wicket framework.

here is my code:

```
        List<DeliveryFormat> formatChoices = lookupProcessor.getLookupValues(DeliveryFormat.class);

        //add(new RadioChoice("deliveryFormat", formatChoices, new ChoiceRenderer<DeliveryFormat>("label")));

        //Add the check boxes for Delivery format
        ChoiceRenderer<DeliveryFormat> deliveryFormatShippment = new ChoiceRenderer<DeliveryFormat>("label", "id");
        CheckBoxMultipleChoice<DeliveryFormat> deliveryChoices = new CheckBoxMultipleChoice<DeliveryFormat>(
                "deliveryFormat", formatChoices, deliveryFormatShippment);
        add(deliveryChoices);
        add(new DeliveryFormatValidator(deliveryChoices));
        final WebMarkupContainer deliveryFormatCountryValue = new WebMarkupContainer("deliveryFormatCountry");
        deliveryFormatCountryValue.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        deliveryFormatCountryValue.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
        add(deliveryFormatCountryValue);
        deliveryFormatCountryValue.setVisible(DeliveryFormat.DELIVERY_FORMAT_ONE.equals(order.getObject().getDeliveryFormat()));

        final TextArea<String> sampleTextArea = new TextArea<String>("address.country");
        sampleTextArea.add(StringValidator.maximumLength(250)).add(
                InlineErrorFeedback.INSTANCE);
        sampleTextArea.setRequired(true);
        sampleTextArea.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        sampleTextArea.setMarkupId("address.country");
        deliveryFormatCountryValue.add(sampleTextArea);

        deliveryChoices.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("address.country") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  

            @Override
          protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                deliveryFormatCountryValue.setVisible(DeliveryFormat.DELIVERY_FORMAT_ONE.equals(order.getObject().getDeliveryFormat()));
                target.addComponent(deliveryFormatCountryValue);
        }
        });
```

but i unable to do wt ever i want..is any thing wrong in my code?

my HTML page:

USA

Answer (score 1):

The `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior` you are using expects the name of the JavaScript event you want to listen for and not the markup id of an HTML element, as you provided to it.
So for example `new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("change")` would be correct.

In your case you could even use an `OnChangeAjaxBehavior`, since it's exactly made for the type of event you are trying to listen for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this statement

`deliveryChoices.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("address.country") {`

to

`deliveryChoices.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {1`

Comment: Thanks both of them,i changed and tried,but from deliveryformat tables itself i m not getting values